# SlickGrid cell styling lost on Sort

Tags: javascript, css, slickgrid

When sorting the rows in SlickGrid, it seems that they are all destroyed and recreated, thus losing the CSS classes that may have been added at run-time.

For example, I want rows that are "dirty" (that is, have been edited but not yet saved)((I don't auto-commit, but use a Save button on the grid to persist data)) to display differently, specifically displaying a "dirty" icon.

So, when a row is "dirty", one of its cells (an icon column) gains a CSS class to display the proper icon. This however is then lost when rows are sorted. Is there a way to avoid the creation of brand new rows on a sort? Or a different method to accomplish this task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SlickGrid explicitly forbids direct manipulation of the DOM elements it creates with the exception of editors.  If you need to decorate a cell/row with a CSS class, do so using the APIs provided by SlickGrid (custom formatters, row/cell metadata, addCellCssStyles, etc.).  That way, they will persist across re-renders.

Comment: Okay, maybe I am missing something here. But even if I use addCellCssStyles, and style row 0, in column 'icon' to display correctly. Then, I sort. Won't row 0 (the first row) be styled still. When the row that I want to be styled (the one that was "dirty") and is now, say, row 4, no longer has the correct style?

Comment: Right.  This is a side effect of SlickGrid's data abstraction.
Love it or hate it, but that's the underlying architecture that allows for a lot of its flexibility.

The grid itself is not aware of uniquely identified data elements, only rows.  When you re-sort your data, all you're doing is changing the "rows" that the grid sees and tell it to re-render.  All the styles and selection that you set on the grid still operates on "rows", so you need to re-map them.  Take a look at example #4 for how selection re-mapping is done.